# Access 2010 Query across multiple fields

Tags: aggregate

I am an absolute Noob when it comes to Access 2010.  I am trying to figure out what I believe is a common task.
I want to do a Query across multiple fields giving me a total.  Let me give you an example:
I sell fruit, only 3 kinds and say my Table has an ID, Name, Item 1, Item 2, Item 3, and other unrelated fields.
An order could look like this:
ID1  Bill Smith Apples
ID2  John Jones Bananas Apples
ID3  Mary Cross Oranges Bananas Apples

I would want a Query to "Scan" (probably the wrong word) the Item 1 field, Item 2 field, and Item 3 field and return a Totals count as follows:
Apples 3
Bananas 2
Oranges 1
Notice that Apples, Bananas and Oranges can be in ANY Field, in ANY order...

Thank you for your Time and Expertise

Ray

Answer (score 1):

The problem is your table structure, how many items can be in each order, three, four, five? Do you intend to add another column if someone orders six items?

They way to do this is keep orders in one table and the line items in another and link them

Table orders:

| order_id | name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Bill Smith |
| 2 | John Jones |
| 3 | Mary Cross |

Table orderItems:

| item_id | order_id | item |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | Apples |
| 2 | 2 | Bananas |
| 3 | 2 | Apples |
| 4 | 3 | Bananas |
| 5 | 3 | Apples |
| 6 | 3 | Oranges |

Then use a query which joins the two tables together:

```sql
select o.order_id,o.name,oi.item from orders o left join orderItems oi on o.order_id = oi.order_id
```

Will give an output of:

| Order_ID | Name | Item |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Bill Smith | Apples |
| 2 | John Jones | Apples |
| 2 | John Jones | Bananas |
| 3 | Mary Cross | Apples |
| 3 | Mary Cross | Bananas |
| 3 | Mary Cross | Oranges |

Comment: I used the simple 3 item apples, bananas, oranges scenario because I have around 30 different Items to sell on Etsy.

Comment: I have a Table with Name, Sale $, other sale related fields and 30 fields labeled Item 1, Item 2, Item 3 etc.  all the way to 30.  Right now I'm inputting this info into a SIMPLE Excel spreadsheet.  I have now created a simple Form in Access 2010 to input the same data I was inputting into the Excel spreadsheet.  Item 1 etc just refers to what item they ordered first etc.  EVERYONE has something in Item 1 field.  If someone ordered 6 things from me at the same time, I would have data in Fields "Item 1 all the way to Item 6".

Comment: And therein lies your problem. You need to use Access like the database it is, and not like Excel..

Comment: @Ray98GoVols The answer given by Tom is correct. You should arrange your data tables in a similar way. And please don't be rude - users here are volunteers, if someone takes time to give you an answer,  please don't lash out at them.

Comment: @Ray98GoVols What exactly is your problem? Nobody has been rude towards you, on the contrary. So what is the actual problem? How does this answer not help you? What exactly do you need? You do know that you have to start with a database table design, apparently.